# How to push long whitespace to next line in a pre-wrap html

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap, pre

I'm trying to make a kind of text editor that preserves long whitespace and doesn't hide it also on line breaks, but instead pushes it to next line.

```
|That means that if i have a  |
|line like this one here      |
```

And I insert two more spaces at the end of the first line, i want to get

```
|That means that if i have a  |
| line like this one here     |
```

One space was added to the end of the first line, but then when there was no more room, the next space was wrapped to the next line.

And here with all typed spaces shown as underscores, this:

```
|That_means_that_if_i_have_a_ |
|line_like_this_one_here      |
```

to this:

```
|That_means_that_if_i_have_a__|
|_line_like_this_one_here     |
```

Is there a way to do it just in html/css?

I can imagine how to do it in javascript, but would like to avoid.

Comment: please post relevant code

Comment: yeah, edited - want to know if possible just in html/css, no relevant code to post

Comment: you can use `&nbsp;` to preserve whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you write text , write a space like this `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use css property  `white-space: pre;` on parent class to preserve whitespaces in HTML

```
.classname tagname { white-space: pre; }
```

e.g.

```
.editor a, .editor td, .editor span { white-space: pre; }
```

HTML for this would look like as follows

```
<div class="editor">
    <!-- span a td-->
</div>
```